# oracle how convert value to variable object name

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

sorry for my english....

I have the names of the variables in a table. I need to recover these names to be used with the values of the calculated variables.

```
    CREATE TABLE S2V_AMG_FLUSSI
(
  COD_COMPAGNIA  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  ID_FLUSSO      INTEGER,
  DS_FLUSSO      VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  DS_CONDIZIONE  CLOB
);

Insert into S2V_AMG_FLUSSI
   (COD_COMPAGNIA, ID_FAMIGLIA_FLUSSI, DS_FAMIGLIA_FLUSSI, ID_FLUSSO, DS_FLUSSO, 
    DS_CONDIZIONE)
 Values
   ('32', 41, 'compagnia', 2, 'REVALORIZED', 
    'c_variabile');

declare
c_variabile varchar2(12) := 'aaa';
v_sql clob;
v_campo varchar2(100);
v_valore    varchar2(100);   
begin
    select ds_condizione into v_campo from S2V_AMG_FLUSSI
    where cod_compagnia=32
    and id_flusso=1;

    v_sql:='begin select :v_campo into :v_out from dual; end;' ;
    execute immediate v_sql
    USING v_campo , OUT v_valore;

 dbms_output.put_line(v_valore);
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('ERRORE: '||sqlerrm);
end;
```

OUTPUT: c_variabile

but I want: aaa

Comment: sorry, they were written by tests precedenty

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is hard to write for many reasons. One is the abstract nature of the code. Your statement ...

```
v_sql:='begin select :v_campo into :v_out from dual; end;' ;
```

... produces a query which returns the contents of `v_campo`. But what you want is a query which returns the contents of the variable whose name is stored in `v_campo`.

Suppose you wrote this:

```
v_sql:='begin select ' || v_campo ||' into :v_out from dual; end;' ;
execute immediate v_sql
USING  OUT v_valore;
```

It hurls, because `c_variabile` is an invalid identifier in the scope of the query.

This will work ...

```
v_sql:='begin select :'||v_campo||' into :v_out from dual; end;' ;
execute immediate v_sql
USING c_variabile, OUT v_valore;
```

... but is patently useless because it hard codes the very thing you want soft.

What does appear to work is:

```
declare
    c_variabile varchar2(12) := 'aaa';
    v_sql clob;
    v_campo varchar2(100) := 'c_variabile' ;
    v_valore    varchar2(100);   
begin

    v_sql:='declare '||v_campo||' varchar2(12) := :P1; begin select '|| 
                                            v_campo||' into :v_out from dual; end;' ;
    execute immediate v_sql
    USING 'aaa', OUT v_valore;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_valore);
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('ERRORE: '||sqlerrm);
end;
```

This solves the problem posed by your question but feels like cheating. And it feels like cheating because it is cheating: the generated code doesn't use the defined variable `c_variabile`, it uses the hardcoded  value `'aaa'` instead.

Which raises the pertinent question, *where does the value `'aaa'` come from?*. Probably you need to rethink your approach, because it seems likely you need a solution which handles the dynamic acquisition of values like `'aaa'` as well as dynamically processing them.

Like I said, Dynamic SQL is tricky stuff.

Comment: Thanks,exactly, I process all the variables at the beginning of the code, then I use these according to the condition written in the clob.

this processing takes place within a for loop, and for each cycle all the variables are used for different conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the ticks from the variable name.

```
Insert into S2V_AMG_FLUSSI
(COD_COMPAGNIA, ID_FAMIGLIA_FLUSSI, DS_FAMIGLIA_FLUSSI, ID_FLUSSO, DS_FLUSSO, DS_CONDIZIONE)
Values ('32', 41, 'compagnia', 2, 'REVALORIZED', c_variabile);
```

Comment: oh no, I wrote the insert to create the example